# How to make text view display temperature data from another method?

Tags: android, text, methods, textview, temperature

Here is the entire code for the app. I don't beleive I have a play method:

```
package com.solomonreedstudios.thermometer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements  SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mTemperature;

public TextView tv1;
public TextView tv2;

public TextView tv3;


SoundPool beepInt;
int beep;


@Override
public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensor_actvity);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);

    beepInt = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    beep = beepInt.load(this, R.raw.beep, 1);

    // Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of
    // a particular sensor.
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mTemperature = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
}

@Override
public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
}

@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // Do something with this sensor data.
    float lux = event.values[0];
    float fahrenheit = lux * 9 / 5 + 32;
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(lux));
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(fahrenheit));
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //  register  a listener for the sensor.
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTemperature, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the ACTIVITY pauses.
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}



public final void collectData(View view) {


    new CountDownTimer(300, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv3.setText("seconds remaining until reading: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            beepInt.play(beep, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            tv3.setText("Your Temperature Is  " + mTemperature);

        }
    }.start();

}

     }
```

Could this help?

Comment: What is your problem? Are you getting any error? If so, logcat should be posted here.

Comment: It just will not put the temperature for the life of me. When I try to use the float that is named Fahrenheit it does not show up or work. How can i get that float to work in the method with my beep and "your temperature is"?

Comment: Where have you called collectData method?

Comment: I believe it is collected in the onSensorChanged

Comment: That is where the temperatures are displayed initially

Comment: You haven't called that method. Call that

Comment: Could you help me out possibly? (Total noob)

Comment: What issue are you facing ??

Comment: I need the data that gets displayed in tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(fahrenheit));

Comment: To get displayed in public void onFinish() {
            beepInt.play(beep, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            tv3.setText( YOUR Temperature Is  " +);       <--------------

Comment: Have you call this method `collectData()` anywhere in your xml file for button or any other UI?

Comment: yes as an on click. It starts a count down, and then after 30 secconds, the temperature should display... But i am having issues since it's in a different method

Comment: Sorry different method means???

Comment: I mean its up with the public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent EVENT) { and it wount go with the collectData for some reason...

Comment: Whenever you change your sensor that means it will display the data in textView every time. And if you want to call collectData function then you need to remove View object from parameter.

Comment: So then i can use the fahrenheit float then?

Comment: Nah.. Its already in float.

Comment: i just need to use that in the collectData so i can show that after the timer is done.

Comment: Oh. Then its too easy. You need to make `float fahrenheit` global in declaration part.

Comment: Then this will make me sound even dumber.... how can i do that

Comment: Means don't you know about globalization ??

Comment: Yeah i dont i just got started with this

Comment: You need to make it same as you declared your `TextView tv1`

Comment: Could you give me an example im still struggling

Comment: Make `float fahrenheit` same as `TextView tv1` and access it by `fahrenheit = lux * 9 / 5 + 32;`

Comment: Where should i put this at? Sorry for many questions just trying to figure this out.